# Bootsrap 3 carousel not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

this is my code for my bootstrap carousel, my prev and next button is not working. I cant seem to see what is the problem.

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div id="img-slider" class="caroussel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 

        <!--  dots  -->

        <!-- wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">  

           <div class="item active"> 
               <img src="img/MNB-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"/>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-caption"> 
                 <h1>University of Surrey Breakdancing society</h1>
            </div>

           <div class="item">  
              <img src="img/MNB-2.jpg"/>
           </div>

           <div class="item">  
              <img src="img/MNB-3.jpg"/>
           </div>

           <div class="item">  
              <img src="img/MNB-4.jpg"/>
           </div>

           <div class="item">  
              <img src="img/MNB-5.jpg"/>
           </div>
        </div>

        <!-- next and previous buttons -->
       <a class="left carousel-control" href="#img-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
       </a>

        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#img-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
       </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

i split my website into various php pages that link together via require or include. maybe this could be a factor to consider, but i have spent time trying to figure out whats going on but i just cant put my finger on it...

Comment: typo error in `caroussel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spelling error: **carousel**, not **caroussel**

```
<div id="img-slider" class="caroussel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

should be

```
<div id="img-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

Working example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div id="img-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/2500x500/f00" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/2500x500/000" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#img-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#img-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. Captions go inside the items.

i.e. Change this:

```
<div class="item active"> 
  <img src="img/MNB-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"/>
</div>

<div class="carousel-caption"> 
  <h1>University of Surrey Breakdancing society</h1>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="item active"> 
  <img src="img/MNB-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"/>
  <div class="carousel-caption"> 
    <h1>University of Surrey Breakdancing society</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but the left and right arrows still dont work.